# Selecting field from all comments on a particular node

Tags: 7, entities, rating

I have essentially hacked comments into reviews of a node, having a comment field of 'rating' with a fivestar widget. I was hoping it would be a trivial call to the voting API to fetch the rating of each 'review' so I could work out a nodes average rating.

However I notice that for some reason all the votes are getting saved in a database table of `field_revision_field_product_rating`, and this contains *no direct foreign key to the node it is from*, is there a 'Drupal' way of fetching the comments in manual SQL with some monster joins?

Just to confirm, review is actually a comment, and the fivestar 'rating' is a field on the comment.

Bonus points: Why, even though I'm using fivestar, are the votes not getting put into the votingAPI storage?

Comment: load all cid of a node using comment_get_thread.

Comment: unfortunately that isn't sufficient as it *requires* you to supply a limit - which I can never know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the field settings screen, it is important to set the “Voting
target” to “Parent node,” so that these votes will add ratings to the node; then,
click the “Save field settings” button

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction, however I've now found that the votes being counted are in correct, for example I have voted with 2 different users on a node, and yet there is only one entry in the voteingapi_vote table and therefore the average is wrong. I have tested this multiple times.

Comment: ok after some more fiddling I've worked out the votingapi doesn't like multiple votes from the same user.